# How to intend Query properly in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to intend Query properly in PHP?

```
$where = "MONTH('leave_date') = ".$data['currM']."' AND YEAR('leave_date') = '".$data['currY']."' AND agent_id = '".$list->ps_crm_agent_id;
```

**DB Error;**

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' AND YEAR('leave_date') = '2019' AND `agent_id` = '7' at line 3

```
SELECT `ps_crm_agent_leaves`.* FROM `ps_crm_agent_leaves` WHERE 
MONTH('leave_date') = 11' AND YEAR('leave_date') = '2019' AND `agent_id` = '7
```

Comment: Thanks, @Simply Ged!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some single quotes

```php
$where = "MONTH('leave_date') = '".$data['currM']."' AND YEAR('leave_date') = '".$data['currY']."' AND agent_id = '".$list->ps_crm_agent_id."'";
                                ^                                                                                                            ^      
                               here                                                                                                     here
```